# PHP detecting line breaks in text field

Tags: php, forms

I'm trying to split up the POST data of a text form field.
I want the data split by each line, using the explode() function

So first I check the POST result for strange characters;

```
$mails = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["emails"]);
```

Then I run this, which doesn't work

```
$emails = explode("\r\n", $mails);
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it not \r\n ? Is my sql escape bit messing me up?

Comment: `\r` is enough as a delimiter

Comment: You don't escape the input for SQL context prior actually concatenating it into a database query (better yet, and simpler at least, try prepared statements/bound params). And linebreaks come in three flavours, CRLF, CR, LF; so consider `preg_split` and `\R` to capture all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also convert the new lines to breaks, then explode from the `<br />`s:

```
$mails = mysql_real_escape_string(nl2br($_POST["emails"]));
$emails = explode("<br />", $mails);
```

Answer (score 2):

> So first I check the POST result for strange characters;
>
> ```
> $mails = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["emails"]);
> ```

Some news here: No you did not. You just did *something* without understanding what you did. That is just *doing strange* not checking something for something strange.

And then you need to explode on the line-separator character used. Looks like it was not `"\r\n"`, next try is `"\n"` and `"\r"` *as well*:

```
$emails = preg_split("/\R/u", $_POST["emails"], -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

(assuming you've got UTF-8 input)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
function guessLineEndings( $aString ) {

  assert( is_string( $aString ));

  if ( FALSE !== strpos( $aString, "\r\n" )) {
     return 1;
  } else if ( FALSE !== strpos( $aString, "\n" )) {
     return 2;
  } else if ( FALSE !== strpos( $aString, "\r" )) {
     return 3;
  } else {
     return -1;
  }

}
```

Note, that you can't guess an line endings, if input is a single line.

And don't forget this, if you run dynamic SQL-queries:

> Never use escaping using e.g. mysql_real_escape_string()! Always use prepared statements!

Pleas review [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/)'s [PHP Security Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Security_Cheat_Sheet#Escaping_is_not_safe) to learn about this: **Escaping is not safe!**

Comment: you are looking for having a specific character sequence at least once, explode most likely is not the best way to find out.

Comment: Actually in your case you could look for \r and \n and then if they come after each other or which one first :D